Selling replica items without original brand name/ logo is halal or haram?
Assalam o Alaikum
If I copy the design of the product of any brand & sell it without original brand logo/ name, even without without any brand name/ logo, will it be halal or haram to sell the replica item without any brand name/ logo?

As long as the item itself is halal to use and the buyer is made aware of the defect in it (i.e. he is told that it is not original).

Please clear my doubt. If the design of a product of a brand is copied and the gloves are made exactly like the gloves of that brand but the brand name & logo is not mentioned on the gloves, not even any logo or company name is mentioned on the gloves, will those gloves fall into the category of counterfeit product or not?
